# Кнопка для удаления yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть ActiveForm в index.php, в контроллере получаю данные с формы и далее работаю уже с данными.
Как передать в форму понятно, но вопрос, как в эту форму добавить кнопку удаления записи?

Comment: Вы в самой форме хотите добавить кнопку и далее обработать в контроллере и удалить?

Comment: Получается что да

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во View:

```
<a href="<? echo Url::to(['test/delete', 'id' => $model->id]) ?>" onclick="return confirm('Вы уверены?')" >Удалить</a>
```

Или

```
<? echo Html::a('Удалить', Url::to(['test/delete', 'id' => $model->id])) ?>
```

В контроллере:

```
use app\models\TestModel;
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function actionDelete($id = false)
    {
        if (isset($id)) {
            if (TestModel::deleteAll(['in', 'id', $id])) {
                $this->redirect(['index']);
            }
        } else {
            $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Где TestModel - имя модели
     Тут есть примеры по удалению записей: [Перейти](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/delete-query/)

Comment: а test имя модели или контроллера?

Comment: Поправил свой ответ. Думаю теперь будет намного яснее